# Why doesn't anything happen when I select a search action from the CiviCRM search results?

Tags: drupal, search-results, select2

I'm in CiviCRM 5.5.0 and everything works perfectly - except that nothing happens when I select a search action like "Add an activity".  There are no errors in the Javascript console.  What's happening?

Comment: Getting this same issue on CiviCRM 5.33.5 on Drupal 8.9.17. Occurs for any set of search results that has the action drop down... the dropdown is made active when one or more contacts are selected, but no action is exe Select2 is installed on Drupal, but even with it disabled no search action is available. (Noting that v8.x of Select2 does not provide for exclusion rules.)

Answer (score 2):

The cause was that I had the "Select2" Drupal module installed, which was adding a second Select2 widget to my search actions, breaking them.

To resolve:

- Go to Drupal **Configuration menu » User Interface » Select2**.
- Click the **Exclusion Rules** tab.
- Under *Don't load Select2 for specific pages*, enter `civicrm/*` and save your changes.

This should fix your search actions.

[image]